# How can I stream program output to wxpython listctrl?

Tags: python, stream, wxpython, output, stdout

I'm making project for school, which is temperature measuring platform with raspberry pi and i'm trying it to stream my data continuous into GUI. Please help.

I have a problem with putting output to wxListCtrl.
This is my code:

```
import spidev
import time
import math
from time import strftime
import string
import os

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
filename = strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H_%M_%S")

def read_adc(adcnum):
# read SPI data from MCP3304 chip, 8 possible adc's (0 thru 7)
    if adcnum > 7 or adcnum < 0:
        return -1

# Frame format: 0000 1SCC | C000 000 | 000 000
    r = spi.xfer2([((adcnum & 6) >> 1)+12 , (adcnum & 1) << 7, 0])
    adcout = ((r[1] & 15) << 8) + r[2]
    return adcout

def make_sure_path_exists(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError:
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            raise

def get_temperature(adc):
# read thermistor voltage drop and convert it to degrees of Celsius
    value = read_adc(adc)               #read the adc
    volts = (value * 3.3) / 4095        #calculate the voltage

    # check if the thermistor is connected to this channel
    if volts > 3.2:
        return 0

    ohms = (volts*10000)/(3.3-volts)    #calculate thermistor resistance
    lnohm = math.log1p(ohms)            #take ln(ohms)

    # a, b, & c values from www.rusefi.com/Steinhart-Hart.html
    # 0-50 C
    a =  0.001125256672
    b =  0.0002347204473
    c =  0.00000008563052732

    # Steinhart Hart Equation
    # T = 1/(a + b[ln(ohm)] + c[ln(ohm)]^3)
    t1 = (b*lnohm)                      #b[ln(ohm)]
    c2 = lnohm                          #c[ln(ohm)]
    t2 = c*math.pow(c2,3)               #c[ln(ohm)]^3
    temp = 1/(a + t1 + t2)              #calcualte temperature in K
    tempc = temp - 273.15               #K to C

    #print out info
    #print ("%4d/4095 => %5.4f V => %6.1f ? => %5.2f °K => %3.1f °C from adc     %d" % (value, volts, ohms, temp, tempc, adc))
    print ("%3.1f °C from sensor %d" % (tempc, adc))

    return tempc

make_sure_path_exists("./data")
'''while True:
    #write to log
    log = open("./data/"+filename+'.csv', 'a') #open a text file for logging
    log.write(strftime("%d/%m/%y,%H:%M:%S"))
    for x in range (0,8):
        log.write(",%3.1f" % (get_temperature(x)))
    log.write(strftime("\n"))
    log.close()
    time.sleep(5)'''

class Myframe(wx.Frame):

    def Close(self, event):
        dialog=wx.MessageDialog(self, 'For sure?', 'End work',  style=wx.OK | wx.CANCEL)
        x=dialog.ShowModal()
        dialog.Destroy()
        if x == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Close()


    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Temperature Monitoring", size=(1024,760))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0


        MenuListwa=wx.MenuBar()
        ProgMenu=wx.Menu()
        ProgMenuItem1=ProgMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,'Temperature','Read data')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OpenData, ProgMenuItem1)
        MenuListwa.Append(ProgMenu,'Data')

        ProgMenu=wx.Menu()
        ProgMenuItem1=ProgMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'End', 'End program')
        MenuListwa.Append(ProgMenu, 'Exit')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Close, ProgMenuItem1)
        self.SetMenuBar(MenuListwa)


        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,600),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Record', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Temperature', width=800)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Add record')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onStartTimer)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.add_records, self.timer)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

def onStartTimer(self, event):
        print 'rekordy'
        self.timer.Start(10)

def add_records(self, event):
    while True:
        Temp=[]
        for ch in range(0,8):
            Temp.append(get_temperature(ch))
        line = "Record %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        add1 = self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, Temp[self.index])
        for i in Temp:
            add1 += self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, Temp[self.index])
        self.index += 1
        time.sleep(30)


# Run
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)         
    frame = Myframe()
    frame.Show()
    frame.Update()
    app.MainLoop()
```

snippet:

```
def onStartTimer(self, event):
    print 'records'
    self.timer.Start(10)
    time.sleep(10)

def add_record(self, event):
    while True:           
        for ch in range(0,8):
            Temp.append(get_temperature(ch))
        line = "Record %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        add1 = self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, str(Temp[self.index]))
        for i in Temp:
            add1 += self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, str(Temp[self.index]))
        self.index += 1
```

Comment: can't you execute `get_temperature(adc)` directly in wxpython using `wx.Timer()` to get data periodically.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it. Can You show me example?

Comment: I'm trying all day long but I can't figure it out. Please help me :)

Comment: do you want it to just keep adding measurements to the list or keep updating the first item in the list? Why is the measuring program separate from the UI?

Comment: I want to keep adding measurments to the list. I edited my code. I get a console output but i need it in ListCtrl. And i need a 10 seconds period of measure.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a wx.Timer and bind it to an event that will update your list control, add this to the end of the frame's **init** method

```
TIMER_ID = wx.NewId()
self.timer = wx.Timer(id=TIMER_ID)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, id=TIMER_ID)
self.timer.Start(10*1000)


def on_timer(self, event):
    self.add_records()


def add_records(self):
    for ch in range(0, 8):
        temp = get_temperature(ch)
        line = "Record %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, temp)
        self.index += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get TypeError: 'Timer' object is not callable

Comment: This should not work properly: ``time.sleep`` will block the wx eventloop from running. See [long running tasks](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) how to deal with blocking tasks by spinning off a thread.

Comment: whoops, I was clearly distracted when I answered this

Comment: Can someone repair it?

Comment: Yep, now I get my list out of range.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're wanting it to do, but the most recent edit should fix your out of range error

Comment: Thanks nepix32, your suggestion is my solution.

Comment: If it answered your question satisfactorily feel free to accept it as the answer. Thanks